# How to print or transfer onto mugs?

Tags: print-design, print-production, screen-printing

PLEASE HELP knowledgeable people :)
I am wondering what the process is in applying a design to the surface of a mug. I want to experiment with patterns and text and create something that looks modern and trendy. As Im a graphic designer the design parts easy, I just wonder how I get the design onto the mug in a cheap and professional finish as I am hoping to sell these. I really like the gold foil look and also just plain black, I have tried sharpies and porcelain paint but the finish doesn't look refined.
I would prefer for them to be dishwasher and microwave safe and a method that I can achieve at home.

Thanks heaps, looking forward to some answers :)[image]

Comment: From your question I'm deducing you want to draw on the mugs *yourself*, is this correct?

Comment: There are a lot of [tutorials](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Photo-Mugs), but I suggest you to select a decent print service, send your image and receive the final mug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are other processes but from my experience, the way you do this is to first mold the mug with ceramic or pottery type material (not sure the correct terminology, sorry) or buy it unfinished. Then you can either paint, apply design via decal of sorts, then cover in glaze and put in a kiln for a certain amount of time. If there are other methods, I'd love to hear about them.

Answer (score 0):

Great that gives me an idea, I am thinking the best way is to make stencils from vinyl add colour and remove and bake. I need to do some research on what how and what glaze you can use and methods of applying possibly porcelain paint so it leaves a smooth finish...:)